# Let $θ\sim\text{Unif}([0,2\pi])$ and define $X_k=\sin(kθ)$, $k\in\Bbb N$. Show that $(X_1+⋯+X_n)/n→0$ a.e

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $θ$ be uniformly distributed on $[0, 2\pi]$ and define $X_k= \sin k\theta 
(k= 1,2, ...)$ . Show that $(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n\to0$ a.e

Attempts:Let $S_n=(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$,from Kolmogorov's Inequality we get for any $\epsilon>0,P\{\max\limits_{1\leq j\leq n}S_j\geq\epsilon\}\leq 1/(n\epsilon^2)$,but how to get $P\{\lim_n S_n\neq0\}=0$?

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thanks a lot but Weyl's theorem is a little beyond what I've learnt (the prob is an exercise of probability course),so is there any methods through convergence theorems or Laws of Large Numbers?

Comment: The Law of large numbers is not applicable here due to lack of independence. Weyl's equidistribution theorem has the feeling of the law of large numbers; however it is much simpler to prove by means of Calculus. There are some postings in MSE that address this, for example this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4359098/121671)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from [Weyl's equidistribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) theorem.

Since $\theta$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,2\pi]$,  $\mathbb{P}[\theta/2\pi\in\mathbb{Q}^c]=1$. Since $\sin$ is Riemann integrable in in $[0,2\pi]$, Weyl's theorem [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4359098/121671) that
the average $\frac{X_1(\theta)+\ldots + X_n(\theta)}{n}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0\sin(t)\,dt=0$.

---

- The fact that $\theta k/2\pi$ is *equidistributed* on $[0,1]$ $\mod 1$ when $\theta/2\pi$ is irrational is a well known fact and has been discussed in MSE before. Many books of Probability discuss this example in their treatment of ergodic theory (see Billingsley, P.,  *Probability and Measure*, third edition, New York, Wiley  1995, or Durrett, *Probability: Theory and Examples*, fifth edition, Cambridge University Press, 2019.)
- Weyl's equidistribution theorem can be studied without use of heavy machinery from Ergodic theory by means of Calculus (Riemann integration, and Weierstrass density theorem)

---

Note that that the random variables $X_n(\theta)=\sin(k\theta)$ have mean $0$ and are orthogonal:
$$\frac1{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0\sin(n\theta)\,d\theta=0,\qquad \frac1{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0\sin(n\theta)\sin(m\theta)\,d\theta=\frac12\delta_{n,m}$$
Hence a weak law of large numbers holds, that is, let $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$. Then
$$\mathbb{E}\Big[\Big|\frac{S_n}{n}\Big|^2\Big]=\frac{1}{2n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
Thus $\frac1nS_n$ converges to $0$ in $L_2$, in probability and thus, almost surely through a subsequence.