# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t = 1}^{n}e^{-k\cos^2(\omega t)}$, where $k>0$ and $0<\omega<\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, computational-mathematics

Need to evalute a closed form expression of the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t = 1}^{n}e^{-k\cos^2(\omega t)}$$
where $k>0$ and $0<\omega<\pi$.

Empirically, I have observed that the limit exists and it does not depend on $\omega$, it depends only on $k$. Also, the value of the limit decreases as $k$ increases, which means the limit is a decreasing function in $k$. I need to prove that the limit is independent of $\omega$ and is a decreasing function in $k$.  Please help me in finding the limit.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Does $f(k)=e^{-k/2}I_0(k/2)$ look like the values you've gotten? ($I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind). $f(1)=0.6450352704$, $f(2)=0.4657596076$, $f(3)=0.3674336091$.

Comment: When $\theta=\frac{\omega}{2\pi}$ is irrational, the sequence $n\theta$ is equidistributed in $[0,1]$. See [Weyl's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4358873/121671) which also states what the limit of the sequence in your posting is.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, I have got the same values empirically. However, I am having a little issue with the mathematical proof of the form of $f(k)$ you have provided. Also I need to show that $f(k)$ is a decreasing function in k. Kindly guide me.

Comment: For a given $n$, can you show that the sum is decreasing in $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\omega$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, then, because $\omega j$ is equidistributed mod $\pi$, it can be shown that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^ne^{-k\cos^2(\omega j)}
&=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi e^{-k\cos^2(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1a}\\
&=e^{-k/2}I_0(k/2)\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
where $I_0$ is the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1).

However, this does not holds when $\omega$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$. For example,
$$
\hspace{-20pt}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^ne^{-k\cos^2(\omega j)}=\left\{\begin{array}{}
e^{-k}&\small\text{if $\omega$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$}\\
\frac{1+e^{-k}}2&\small\text{if $\omega$ is an odd multiple of $\frac\pi2$}\\
\frac{e^{-k}+2e^{-k/4}}3&\small\text{if $\omega$ is a multiple of $\frac\pi3$, but not of $\pi$}\\
\frac{1+e^{-k}+2e^{-k/2}}4&\small\text{if $\omega$ is a multiple of $\frac\pi4$, but not of $\frac\pi2$}\\
\frac{e^{-k}+2e^{-k\phi^2/4}+2e^{-k\phi^{-2}/4}}5&\small\text{if $\omega$ is a multiple of $\frac\pi5$, but not of $\pi$}\\
\frac{1+e^{-k}+2e^{-3k/4}+2e^{-k/4}}6&\small\text{if $\omega$ is a multiple of $\frac\pi6$, but not of $\frac\pi3$ or $\frac\pi2$}
\end{array}\right.
$$